# How to format csv with commas inside entry using bash script?

Tags: mysql, bash, csv, sed

As of now, we have a .csv file with this format:

```
(entry 1, a, b, c, d),(entry 2, a, b, c, d),(entry 3, a, b, c, d) ...
```

I would like to format the csv in such a way that each entry will be its own line, meaning I want to make it look like this:

```
entry 1, a, b, c, d
entry 2, a, b, c, d
entry 3, a, b, c, d
...
```

The problem with this is that there are commas that exist within the parentheses. Is there a way to ignore the commas within the brackets, and use the commas outside the brackets as a separator?

Edit:

The entries inside the parantheses actually look like this:

```
(1,'B000F83SZQ','[0, 0]',5,'I enjoy vintage books and movies so I enjoyed reading this book.  The plot was unusual.  Don\'t think killing someone in self-defense but leaving the scene and the body without notifying the police or hitting someone in the jaw to knock them out would wash today.Still it was a good read for me.','05 5, 2014','A1F6404F1VG29J','Avidreader','Nice vintage story',1399248000),(2,'B000F83SZQ','[2, 2]',4,'This was a fairly interesting read.  It had old- style terminology.I was glad to get  to read a story that doesn\'t have coarse, crasslanguage.  I read for fun and relaxation......I like the free ebooksbecause I can check out a writer and decide if they are intriguing,innovative, and have enough of the command of Englishthat they can convey the story without crude language.','04 4, 2014','A795DMNCJILA6','dot','Oldie',1396569600),(3,'B000F83SZQ','[1, 1]',5,'I\'d never read any of the Amy Brewster mysteries until this one..  So I am really hooked on them now.','02 19, 2014','A1FV0SX13TWVXQ','Elaine H. Turley \"Montana Songbird\"','I really liked it.',1392768000)
```

After trying James Brown's code, I get this output:

[image]

Comment: You are not using GNU awk as instructed. It's GNU awk only, the `FPAT` isn't in the other awks. Awk default `FS` is space (++), that's where fields get split in your image.

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough:

```
sed 's/^(//;s/)$//;s/),(/\n/g' youfile
```

it removes the leading `(` with the first `s` command, the trailing `(` with the second `s` command, and all the inner `)` and `(` with the third `s` command.

Now that I think about it, it is a bit ugly.

This one is nicer:

```
sed 's/(\([^)]*\))\(,\|$\)/\1\n/g' yourfile
```

as it matches all opening `(`, followed by a sequence of non-`)`, which is captured by `\(` and `\)`, followed by the closing `)` and either the comma or the end of line, and it substitutes it with the captured string with a newline `\n` appended.

The following command generates a bit of you input and processes it with the `sed` command above:

```
echo -e '(entry 1, a, b, c, d),(entry 2, a, b, c, d),(entry 3, a, b, c, d)'  | sed 's/(([^)]*))(,\|$)/\1\n/g'
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it would not create a newline. Instead,  ),( is just replaced with n. So the output now looks like entry 1, a, b, c, d nentry 2, a, b, c, d nentry 3, a, b, c, d ... Thank you so much for your help

Comment: sed 's/(\([^)]*\))\(,\|$\)/\1\n/g' tiny.csv > tiny2.csv

Comment: @danaq that's not my command, as there are some missing backslashes; I wouldn't know where the literal n comes from, however.

Comment: I copy pasted your command. The only thing i changed was saving the changes to a new csv. I have also edited my original question to show how the data entries inside the parantheses looks like.

Comment: The command you pasted here in the comment, which throws an error, misses some backslashes that my command has, as you can see yourself.

Comment: I have amended the command but it still does not work unfortunately...

Comment: Oh, now I see your update, and my command works for that too. I don't know what's wrong with your configuration. Any info on the operating system, `sed`'s version, shell you use?

Comment: I am using macOS Mojave. I cannot seem to check sed's version on my terminal. I am running the commands on my terminal. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @danaq, can you append the outputs of `sed --version` and `echo $SHELL` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one using GNU awk:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="([^,]+)|(\\([^)]+\\))";OFS="\n"}{$1=$1}1' file
```

Output:

```
(entry 1, a, b, c, d)
(entry 2, a, b, c, d)
(entry 3, a, b, c, d)
```

Explained:

```
$ gawk '                           # using GNU awk, not any other awk
BEGIN {                            # in the beginning, back in 1955...
    FPAT="([^,]+)|(\\([^)]+\\))"   # define fields, not separators
    OFS="\n"                       # newline separates when outputing
}
{ $1=$1 }                          # rebuild record
1' file                            # and output
```

**Update**: Where did it get fragmented at?

[image]

Comment: there is a problem with this code because the data inside the parantheses got fragmanted i.e \n has been added at the wrong places, not just at the ),(.

I have added a sample line of the csv in the question.

Comment: Added an image of the output. Where does it get fragmented at? Can't find the place. This output has an extra newline in the `OFS="\n\n"` for clarity. (image will get removed once the problem is solved)

Comment: I have edited my initial question to add a picture as well to show the output

Comment: [Commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59421563/how-to-format-csv-with-commas-inside-entry-using-bash-script/59422230?noredirect=1#comment105031853_59421563) in the OP.

Comment: Thank you. I have done what I should do and installed gawk (brew install gawk). I have updated the output obtained

Comment: `FPAT` was introduced in version 4.0 (per [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Feature-History.html)). Please, see `gawk --version` in case you are running some prehistoric version. In case you have proper version, please cut and paste the exact command you used to get that faulty output to comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -e 's/^(//' -e 's/)$//' -e 's/),(/\
/g' file
```

After the `\` on the first line is a literal newline followed by `/g' file`.

- `'s/^(//'` replace the opening `(` at the start of the line with an empty string
- `'s/)$//'` replace the closing `)` at the end of the lie with an empty string
- `'s/),(/\
  /g'` replace all occurrences of `),(` with a newline, the `g` stands for global

Depending on your `sed` version you can modify the input file in-place with option `-i`:

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i -e 's/^(//' -e 's/)$//' -e 's/),(/\
/g' file
```

With BSD `sed` (macOS):

```
sed -i '' -e 's/^(//' -e 's/)$//' -e 's/),(/\
/g' file
```

Or redirect the output to a new file:

```
sed -e 's/^(//' -e 's/)$//' -e 's/),(/\
/g' file > file.new
```

Comment: thank you, but after trying your command, i get ": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern error

Comment: I think you entered two newlines instead of one. At the end of the first line, enter ```\```, then press the _Enter_ key on your keyboard once and enter `/g' file` on the next line. Then press the _Enter_ key again. It should also work if you copy & paste the command.